# Laptop charger turns off as soon as I plug it in to the laptop. Could it be a bad motherboard?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, battery, laptop-repair

If I unplug the battery and attempt to power the laptop off just AC it works just fine, but as soon as I plug in the battery the charger turns off.

I've tried two different batteries and three different chargers. One of them is a universal I've double checked it with another computer.

Can this be a motherboard problem? If so would there be some sort of way to check for sure without having to just order the replacement and swapping it out?

Comment: Have you ever tried the same charger/battery on another computer of the same model? If they work then definitely your computer is bad...

Comment: Is your AC port on your laptop damaged? It sounds like it could be shorting, which could really damage your hardware.

Comment: @bfrguci I don't have another Dell to check my universal with, but I did try the charger on another laptop (an HP) and it worked fine.

Comment: It is highly likely your computer is bad. I would recommend returning it if it is new...

Comment: @gkubed If the charging port was bad, would it still work with the battery removed? It can power from AC for a long is the battery isn't present. If I turn it on without the battery, and plugged into AC it works. But as soon as I slide the battery in the laptop says charger disconnected and the light on the charger turns off.

Comment: @bfrguci, not new, can't claim a warranty or anything. Repair or replace is the only options.

Comment: Hmm - have you been able to use the laptop without an AC adapter but with a battery with a charge? Also, Make sure the contacts for the battery are not damaged (this may not make much sense for some laptop models).

Comment: @gkubed, yeah laptop works off just battery power if the battery has a charge. However throughout the time I've been working on it though the batteries have depleted and I don't have an alternate way to recharge them.

Battery terminals are also clean and not bent at all.

Comment: Wow, that is odd. I'm assuming it immediately cuts off when you're on battery power and plug in an AC adapter too?

Comment: The computer doesn't cut off, but the charger does. The computer OS never says charger connected and stays on, the light on the charger just immediately turns off when I plug it into the laptop. On all three of the chargers I've used. Even if the computer is off. But only if the battery is connected to the laptop.

Comment: I initially was using a aftermarket charger and I assumed the charger went bad, but I tried it with a stock dell charger, and a universal charger that I know for sure works, and same exact problem on all three of them.

Comment: There's nothing I can really resort to except your original diagnosis. Either your motherboard is bad, or some of the wiring/connections between the AC port and motherboard, or motherboard and battery is messed up. Unfortunately, when it comes to motherboards, you're kinda on your own when it comes to hardware diagnosing.